# Map gear's OL3-Google-Maps not showing the google layer even after adding google layer

Tags: openlayers, layers, google-maps-api, basemap

I am using Map Gear's OL3-Google-Maps in order to load the google base map in OL3,
I am adding like this

```
//Before adding this i am removing the OSM base map tile layer and adding it.
var googleLayer = new olgm.layer.Google();
this._map.addLayer(googleLayer);
var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({
                map: this._map
            });
olGM.activate();
```

But after adding this i am getting empty white screen,In network the request is also not going to bring the tiles.

Comment: Do you have the answer now? I have same problem.

Comment: @morteza malvandi No not yet

Comment: run `var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({
                map: this._map
            });
olGM.activate();` after 2 seconds. then see result.

Comment: I tried it not working

Comment: See my question at [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194305/why-ol3-google-maps-is-blurred)

Comment: Some questions are receiving no answers maybe because the official place to post them is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3).

Comment: @ManjunathM any solution found? I have same problem?