# Why ol3 google maps is blurred?

Tags: openlayers, google-maps

I'm developing an application using [**GeoExt 3**](https://github.com/geoext/geoext3)([Openlayers 3.15.0](http://openlayers.com) and [Extjs 6.0.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0)). I want to use Google map as base layer using [**ol3 google maps**](https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps).

I add `ol3 google maps` to my project as follow:
`index.html`:

```
<script src="http://dev5.mapgears.com/ol3-google-maps/dist/ol3gm.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev5.mapgears.com/ol3-google-maps/css/ol3gm.css">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now I add google map as follow:

```
var googleLayer = new olgm.layer.Google();
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [googleLayer],
    view: view
});
```

For activating google map, I use follow code:

```
var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({map: map}); // map is the ol.Map instance
olGM.activate();
```

Occur an error as follow:

> ol3gm.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of
>   null
>   [image]

When I set time out as follow, It don't occur any error:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({map: map});
    olGM.activate();
}, 2000);
```

But in this state The map is blurred. See the result:

[image]

But the ol3 google maps sample result at [here](http://dev5.mapgears.com/ol3-google-maps/examples/simple.html) is as follow:
[image]

**Why my result is blurred**? **Where is the problem**?

update:
All things in [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) is OK, This result is in [`Google Chrom 50.0.2661.102`](https://www.google.com/chrome/)